# Using FIND function to return last value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, find, named-ranges

I am trying to write a function which searches through a column and return the cell which contains the last match.

For example, if I have cell A5 as my active cell

```
A1 -> Text
A2 -> wefwqef
A3 -> Text
A4 -> eorbebr
```

I would want to search through the array for 'Text' and for it to return the cell A3 as that is the last match.

But if I have cell A7 as my active cell

```
A1 -> Text
A2 -> wefwqef
A3 -> Text
A4 -> eorbebr
A5 -> fhyeher
A6 -> Text
```

Then it would return A6 as my result.

I have been playing with the FIND function to try and get it to work, but I keep getting errors (Application or object based error).

My plan is to execute this code as part of a larger loop and in each case, it returns the value closest to the active cell. (I hope that makes sense)

This is the code I have so far:

```
    Range("A19:I19").Select
    'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, 5).Value & ":5 CTs,
     O/C " & _
    'Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, 8).Value * 100 & "% @ " & _
    'Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, 9).Value & " TM"


    Dim Rng As Range

      With Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(9, 3), Cells(Line, 3))

        Set Rng = .Find(What:="Primary", _
          After:=.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Line, 3), _
          LookIn:=xlValues, _
          LookAt:=xlPart, _
          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
          MatchCase:=False)
```

I also imagine that when I can get this to work, I would include an DO or IF statement which would say, once value has been stored in Rng then cellx = rng.

Please help! What is wrong with this code??

Comment: Apologies if I have not followed the guidelines correctly, this has been given to me with a very short deadline! I appreciate any help given! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) to hold the values, and then iterate through the array in reverse, until you find the value you're after.

```
Sub arrayFind()
    Dim currRow As Long
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rng as Range
    Dim arrValues() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    currRow = ActiveCell.Row
    arrValues = Range("A1:A" & currRow)

    For i = UBound(arrValues, 1) To LBound(arrValues, 1) Step -1
        If arrValues(i, 1) = "Text" Then
            set rng = Range(Cells(i, 1).Address)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The above creates an array from the `Activecell`, to `A1`. It then searches column A (dimension 1 of the array) for the criteria supplied (in this scenario `Text`) from the last item of the array, to the first. This enables it to find the matching criteria nearest to the `Activecell`.